# How to get blockquote around wrapped photo

Tags: html, css

I just installed a new template on my blog and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to wrap a blockquote around a photo. This is the current blockquote CSS:

```
.post blockquote {
font-style:italic;
background-color:#ECF1F2;
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
border:1px dotted #31484C;
line-height: 1.8em !important;}
```

[This page](http://www.cornerfolds.com/2017/06/audiobook-review-shadow-queen-by-cj.html) shows an example of what I'm attempting to fix and [this page](https://booksandprejudice.blogspot.com/2017/06/audiobook-review-ruins.html) shows what I want it to do.

What do I need to add to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `img` tag inside the block with your text and apply `float: left` to the `img`. That's what floats were made for initially.

Comment: The image is floated left already and I haven't changed the post formatting at all. This is something different in the CSS from the previous theme that was installed.

Comment: But probably it's not inside the text container, otherwise the text would wrap around it...

Answer (score 0):

I've isolated the relevant CSS and made a [simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/uoL7q8u9/1/) that will hopefully make it clearer for you (I've created utility classes to text alignment, as the initial code as inline style in the HTML, which is not best practice.

### Key CSS:

Everything is wrapped in a container `div`. Then the following

```
float: left;
clear: left;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-right: 1em;
```

is applied to the book's thumbnail. Since it is only clearing the left side, content on the right side can flow around it.

By applying `margin` and `padding` to `blockquote`, the illusion of the book popping out of the blockquote is created; however, all that is really happening is that the image clears the left side, for the size of the image. After that, content from the right side is allowed to fill the parent container in full, as is the default nature of block-level elements.